# Setting male or female to an integer from a radio button

Tags: java, android

I have a simple story app and the reader chooses if they are male or female at the start. I have a radio group with boy and girl.

I then want to take this info and use it so that the correct gender wording is displayed. him and her.

I have used this code

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    int radioButtonId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb = findViewById(radioButtonId);

    if (rb.getText().equals("boy")) {
        gender = 1;
    } else {
        gender = 2;
    }
}
```

so that if boy is chosen the  int gender = 1 or else gender = 2.

when a button is pressed for someone to 'talk' it then looks if gender ==1 it will display him or else it will use her.

My problem is that the gender is always ==2. I have used Log.i to check this and I can ever seem to get gender to be 1. even though the boy radiobutton is clicked.

Please could anyone offer any help.

Thanks

Comment: If you add a print statement for `rb.getText()`, what does it print?

Comment: *FYI:* `gender` should be an `enum`. not an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the error is because the text of your radio button doesn't actually say "boy". Maybe "Boy"?

Anyhow, it's better to check on id instead of the text. Assuming that you made the radio group using xml, you should give your buttons ids. For example the id "boy". You can then just do this:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.boy) {
        gender = 1;
    } else {
        gender = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep! simple mistake. I was overthinking it! which is normally my problem. I didn't use capital B in the code! Thanks. I have tried your other code to and that works. I guess my first version is better if there are more than 2 radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by not converting text to `String`. You need to call `toString()` to make comparison. Because `getText()` returns editable type so code should look like: `rb.getText().toString().equals("boy")`. Also check is spelling on word `boy` correct.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using the equals method! This is incorrect! What you want to use is

```
 (rb.getText().compareToIgnoreCase(“boy”) == 0)
```

Equals compares the values memory reference not their actual values, as compareTo will compare the values, returning either 0 for “a match”, -1 or 1 (don’t need to worry about those values, they just means they don’t match)